# Select the record of a given id with the highest timestamp using DAO

Tags: c++, ms-access, dao, recordset

How do I do the following using DAO on a recordset

```
SELECT TOP 1 * FROM foo WHERE id = 10 ORDER BY timestamp DESC
```

Using **SetCurrentIndex** you can only use one index it seems otherwise using **id** and **timestamp** and selecting the first one would work.

Answer (score 0):

I am by no means sure of what you want.

```
Dim rs As DAO.Recordset
Dim db As Database

Set db = CurrentDB

sSQL = "SELECT TOP 1 * FROM foo WHERE id = 10 ORDER BY timestamp DESC"
Set rs = db.OpenRecordset(sSQL)
```

Find does not work with all recordsets. This will work:

```
Set rs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("select * from table1")
rs.FindFirst "akey=1 and atext='b'"

If Not rs.EOF Then Debug.Print rs!AKey
```

This will not:

```
Set rs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("table1")
rs.FindFirst "akey=1 and atext='b'"
```

Comment: I mean if I already have a recordset that I have to work with. Creating my own one is not a problem. But here I have a huge one in a huge system so I don't want to query the DB again to crate a new on. Instead I wonder how to perform this on the existing recordset using *Seek* or something similar.

Comment: The need for code is kind of redundant I think. Imagine having a recordset of data. It's from a table that has at least *id* and *timestamp* in it. How do you perform a *Seek()* on it that would equal the above sql query.

Comment: The point of posting code is that I get to see what kind of recordset you have. The point of the code I posted is that it suggests that there is no reason for you to use seek or find when it is so much faster and easier to simply open a new recordset. I have added some notes.